# How to jest.mock "git-simple" branchLocal function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I use the `simple-git` package. I have the following function:

```
import simpleGit from 'simple-git';

/**
 * The function returns the ticket Id, is presents, in the branch name
 * @returns ticket Id
 */
export const getTicketIdFromBranchName = async (ticketRegex: RegExp) => {
    const git = simpleGit();

    try {
        const localBranches = await git.branchLocal();
        const currentBranch = localBranches.current;
        const currentBranchTicketMatches = currentBranch.match(ticketRegex);

        if (currentBranchTicketMatches) {
            return currentBranchTicketMatches[0];
        }

        return null;
    } catch {
        return null;
    }
};
```

I try to create a unit-test for this function:

```
import { getTicketIdFromBranchName } from '@/utils/git-info';

const TICKET_ID_REGEX = /((?<!([A-Z]{1,10})-?)[A-Z]+-\d+)/.source;

describe('[utils/git-info]', () => {
    it('getTicketIdFromBranchName | Function should proper ticket Id when there is one', async () => {
        const ticketId = 'CLO-1234';

        jest.mock('simple-git', () => {
            const mGit = {
                branchLocal: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ current: `${ticketId} DUMMY TEST` })),
            };

            return jest.fn(() => mGit);
        });

        const result = await getTicketIdFromBranchName(new RegExp(TICKET_ID_REGEX));

        expect(result === ticketId).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

But the unit-test fails. I says I expected to get `true` but it got `false` in the final line.

I guess I use `jest.mock` in the wrong way.

Comment: I'm thinking off in these 2 things: 1)) **result** is not a string, maybe a number (try to do expect(result == ticketId) instead of use triple equal just to check it  - 2)) Despite the fact of *'getTicketIdFromBranchName'* seems to be treat as *async/await*, when you get to the 'expect' instructuion line, **result** have no value (try a console.log(result) right before the line expect(result == ticketId).toEqual(true); )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#examples) has a key description of the use of `jest.mock`.

> Note: In order to mock properly, Jest needs `jest.mock('moduleName')` to be in the same scope as the `require/import` statement.

You call the `jest.mock('moduleName')` inside test case function scope, but `import` the `git-info` module in module scope. That's why mock doesn't work.

Use `require('moduleName')` or `await import('moduleName')` in test case function. The order of the `require/import` and `jest.mock()` statements does **not** matter.

`git-info.js`:

```js
import simpleGit from 'simple-git';

/**
 * The function returns the ticket Id, is presents, in the branch name
 * @returns ticket Id
 */
export const getTicketIdFromBranchName = async (ticketRegex) => {
  const git = simpleGit();

  try {
    const localBranches = await git.branchLocal();
    const currentBranch = localBranches.current;
    const currentBranchTicketMatches = currentBranch.match(ticketRegex);

    if (currentBranchTicketMatches) {
      return currentBranchTicketMatches[0];
    }

    return null;
  } catch {
    return null;
  }
};
```

`git-info.test.js`:

```js
const TICKET_ID_REGEX = /((?<!([A-Z]{1,10})-?)[A-Z]+-\d+)/.source;

describe('[utils/git-info]', () => {
  it('getTicketIdFromBranchName | Function should proper ticket Id when there is one', async () => {
    const { getTicketIdFromBranchName } = await import('./git-info');
    const ticketId = 'CLO-1234';

    jest.mock(
      'simple-git',
      () => {
        const mGit = {
          branchLocal: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ current: `${ticketId} DUMMY TEST` })),
        };

        return jest.fn(() => mGit);
      },
      { virtual: true }
    );

    const result = await getTicketIdFromBranchName(new RegExp(TICKET_ID_REGEX));

    expect(result === ticketId).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71808909/git-info.test.js (7.439 s)
  [utils/git-info]
    ✓ getTicketIdFromBranchName | Function should proper ticket Id when there is one (6892 ms)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |   84.62 |       50 |     100 |   81.82 |                   
 git-info.js |   84.62 |       50 |     100 |   81.82 | 19-21             
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.215 s, estimated 9 s
```

package version: `"jest": "^26.6.3"`